# read coordinate text file for regionprop usage - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a coordinate text file and I wish to read it into a regionprop. I wish to use the regionprop for few analysis like Centroid. How can I do it?

Code:

```
filename = fullfile('E:/outline.txt');

fileID = fopen(filename);
C = textscan(fileID,'%d %d');
fclose(fileID);

stats = regionprops(C,'Centroid')
```

coordinate text file content is as follow:

```
88  10
87  11
87  12
88  13
88  14
92  21
93  22
93  23
94  24
95  25
100 33
101 34
102 34
103 34
103 33
103 32
103 31
103 30
103 29
103 28
103 27
102 26
102 25
101 24
101 23
100 22
100 21
100 20
99  19
99  18
94  12
93  12
92  12
91  11
90  11
89  10
88  10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `centroid`, which was introduced in 2017b?

```
[x,y] = centroid(C);
```

If you are insistent on regionprops (which is slower, and less accurate than operating on the polygon directly) then you are misunderstanding how region props works.  Region props works on images.  You need to first create an image, then pass the image to region props.

```
bw = roipoly(zeros(120), C(:,1), C(:,2));
stats = regionprops(bw);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find [`roipoly`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html?requestedDomain=true) useful: this allows you to convert a list of 2d points/polygon vertices into a binary mask.
The resulting binary mask can then be fed to `regionprops`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried BW = roipoly(C{1}, C{2}) but it is not working, any solution

Comment: Tried: xData = double(C{1}); 
yData = double(C{2}); 
BW = roipoly(xData, yData);
stats = regionprops(BW,'Centroid'); and still dont know what is not ok.

Comment: @jane you are missing the first argument of roipoly.

Comment: So what can I use as the  grayscale or RGB image I (I do not have an image just an outline?

Comment: @jane: `roipoly(zeros(256,256),C{1},C{2})`