# plot coordinate text file for regionprop usage - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Based on a previous question ([read coordinate text file for regionprop usage - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434506/read-coordinate-text-file-for-regionprop-usage-matlab)) I wish to plot the object with an extended boundaries (zeros+10) but it does not work. Any reason why?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;

filename = fullfile('E:/outline.txt');

fileID = fopen(filename);
C = textscan(fileID,'%d %d');
fclose(fileID);

xMax = double(max(C{1})-10)
yMax = double(max(C{2})+10)

bw=roipoly(zeros(xMax ,yMax ),C{1},C{2});
imshow(bw);
stats = regionprops(bw);
```

coordinate text file content is as follow:

```
88  10
87  11
87  12
88  13
88  14
92  21
93  22
93  23
94  24
95  25
100 33
101 34
102 34
103 34
103 33
103 32
103 31
103 30
103 29
103 28
103 27
102 26
102 25
101 24
101 23
100 22
100 21
100 20
99  19
99  18
94  12
93  12
92  12
91  11
90  11
```

Comment: Why does not work........

Comment: can see the object in the plot. if I use for example  bw=roipoly(zeros(500 ,500 ),C{1},C{2});
I can see it but the image is small. I look for a way to extended a bit the bounderies.

Comment: Please, read [mcve] entirely and provide one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xMax = double(max(C{1})-10)
```

That should probably be +10. This way you make the image smaller than your polygon.

If you want to extend the image on the left side also, add an offset to your polygon coordinates:

```
bw = roipoly(zeros(yMax, xMax), C{1}+5, C{2}+5);
```

Note also that I swapped `xMax` and `yMax` from your code, this might be another issue you're seeing. Matrix dimensions are specified as (height, width), as are indices into the matrix. But some functions such as `roipoly` take coordinates with `x` first and `y` second. This is a common pitfall with MATLAB syntax.

I just learned that the above is the same as

```
bw = roipoly(yMax, xMax, C{1}+5, C{2}+5);
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the logic but it still does not work. Any idea how to advance.

Comment: @jane: What does "does not work" mean? Gives an error message? Returns something you didn't expect? What is the issue?

Comment: @jane: I just noticed another issue with your code. Updated answer.

Comment: The issue was that the imshow(bw) was black. Thanks for the updated code. a great help.